# Bulk adding template aka Watermark/image in Premiere pro (asking if it can be done

Tags: batch-processing, template, python, adobe-premiere

My main desires for Video production are:

Take a folder of videos and apply a graphic template under each video in question basically a layer underneath the actual video ( this will prevent a lot of confusion and or problems like parameter cutting or applying a clipping mask unless a clipping mask is more simple to do than what is needed)..

That's it. Incase my caveman Esque description of what the project is called for. I'll show example.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPAGHP6F6Ks&ab_channel=TikTokGOThis shows exactly what I want to do but less visually appeasing version. TikTok Videos have a certain framerate and size. On Both the left and the right the YouTube channel uploader has applied an image template (generic looking) that covers and compensates the format TikTok displays on their site.

Here is example of no template applied https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7mUSQ0dhqs&ab_channel=TikTokLists the uploader just took TikTok Video and rendered it at 1080p

I don't want to trim, I don't want to exchange audio/video codecs. Essentially I would basically be bulk applying a watermark. The only thing I want to change or do is as follows below:

Be able to dictate what layover/watermark gets applied

Be able to choose the directory/folder

I own Adobe suite student edition so I have everything. If any of you know any process of applying actions that can mitigate what the project needs, do tell me, please!If not, if anyone knows the exact jargon I would need to use while hiring someone for 5 dollars on fiverr that are FFmpeg and Python experts that can simply code in under 5 minutes, please, tell me. I know it involves overlay.

I'm also open to finding a software you know that can do this.Thank you and have great days/nights!

The final question is can it be done in Premiere or Media encoder on a batch level? I ask because I searched on Goo and other unknown less popular engines, havn't found an answer.
I did however read something about FFmpeg. Is FFmpeg my only option? I don't have linux but can load it on a server I rent.

Comment: Video questions belong on [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com) but use the search first. I found 40 pages of questions with the keyword ['overlay'](https://video.stackexchange.com/search?q=overlay)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Video editing questions are [off-topic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Sorry about that.  You should flag your question and ask a mod to migrate it to Video Production Stack Exchange.